# ruby externalized SQL module

Tags: sql, ruby, external

Any recommendations for a module which keeps SQL queries external to the application, for Ruby programs?  I'm looking to avoid hardcoding SQL queries and possibly to support multiple SQL backends in a set of programs that make direct SQL queries (that is, not mediated via an ORM).

Hyopthetically:

```
# Production system is pg, dev environment is sqlite
sql_book = What::Module::Here.load( a_file,
                                    ENV['DEVEL'] ? 'PostgreSQL' : 'SQLite3' )

# Okay, now get all Widget IDs
r = db_handle.execute( :load_all_widget_ids )
```

In perl I might use [`Data::Phrasebook::SQL`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Phrasebook/lib/Data/Phrasebook/SQL.pm) or something more exotic like [`CAM::SQLManager`](http://search.cpan.org/~clotho/CAM-SQLManager-1.13/lib/CAM/SQLManager.pm#XML_STRUCTURE).

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I believe this module/gem has to be written first. Seems not to be too complicated. / Did you find any solution after this long time?

Comment: @asaaki, no, not yet.  I've got some unreleased scratchings built on top of the RDBI (Ruby/DBI reboot), however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequel is more lighter and flexible than other ORMs like ActiveRecord and DataMapper:

http://sequel.rubyforge.org/

or you can use Ruby DBI:

https://github.com/RDBI/rdbi  (edited)

maybe you'll want to write some layer to read queries from an external file, as you asked.

Comment: yes!  But please see [`RDBI`](https://github.com/rdbi) rather than the old ruby-dbi.

Comment: Yes, RDBI + file loading helper and everything should work as expected.